# Converting html to be responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design

Let me be clear, my html skills here are poor, to put it mildly.
I ended up doing the unthinkable and making a table in Excel and exporting that. Since that was the only way I could see and tweak the columns and rows exactly how I wanted them since the idea of WYSIWYG editors have gone the way of the dinosaur.

Heresy I know.

Here is the code I am currently using, which I think works great for what I need. But I've run into a small issue on mobile device. The table and it's content doesn't even attempt to wrap, but since this code is so messy, I have no idea where to start.

Any ideas? Code below.

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:847px; text-decoration-thickness:initial; text-decoration-style:initial; text-decoration-color:initial" width="847">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:159pt" width="212" />
    <col style="width:9pt" width="12" />
    <col style="width:467pt" width="623" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-top:1px solid white; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Job Title</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px;border-width: 1px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Name</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; border-width: 1px;  border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Org</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; border-width: 1px;  border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Vacancy Location</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-width: 1px;  border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Brief outline of position</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-width: 1px;     border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Application Closing Date</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-width: 1px;  border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Attachments</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Attachment #1</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-bottom:none; height:40px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:none; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="border-bottom:none; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl65" colspan="3" style="border-bottom:none; height:40px; width:847px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px;border-width: 1px;     border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:1px solid white; border-right:.7px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">POC for further details</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl74" style="border-bottom:none; height:14px; width:212px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl74" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl74" style="border-bottom:none; width:623px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl73" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; border-width: 1px;  border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Name</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl70" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px;border-width: 1px;    border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Email</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl70" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px;border-width: 1px;   border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Phone</span></span></span></span></span></td>
      <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The css can be built by looking at the various class names assigned within the HTML and then creating that as a css class and copying the inline style to that class. Once that is done the inline style can be removed ( per element/class). When all classes are defined the markup will be considerably easier to deal with and tweak

Answer (score 1):

You're going to make life difficult for yourself with all those inline styles but you can overwrite any of them by using the css `!important` tag.

If you add this to your CSS your table will expand and contract within the viewport:

```
table {
   width:100% !important;
}
```

```css
table {
  width:100% !important;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; width:847px; text-decoration-thickness:initial; text-decoration-style:initial; text-decoration-color:initial" width="847">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:159pt" width="212" />
        <col style="width:9pt" width="12" />
        <col style="width:467pt" width="623" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-top:1px solid white; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Job Title</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px;border-width: 1px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Name</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; border-width: 1px;    border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Org</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; border-width: 1px;    border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Vacancy Location</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-width: 1px;    border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Brief outline of position</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl72" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-width: 1px;   border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Application Closing Date</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl69" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-width: 1px;    border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Attachments</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Attachment #1</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom:none; height:40px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:none; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="border-bottom:none; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; vertical-align:bottom; white-space:nowrap; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl65" colspan="3" style="border-bottom:none; height:40px; width:847px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px;border-width: 1px;   border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:1px solid white; border-right:.7px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">POC for further details</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl74" style="border-bottom:none; height:14px; width:212px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl74" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl74" style="border-bottom:none; width:623px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl73" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px; border-width: 1px;    border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Name</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl70" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px;border-width: 1px;  border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-top:1px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Email</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl70" style="border-bottom:1px solid white; height:40px; width:212px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-right:9px; padding-top:1px;border-width: 1px;     border-radius: 5px; margin: 3px; padding-left:1px; background-color:#003e2f; border-top:none; border-right:1px solid white; border-left:1px solid white"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:white"><span style="font-weight:700"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">Phone</span></span></span></span></span></td>
            <td class="xl68" style="border-bottom:none; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; padding-left:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="xl71" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; width:623px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; padding-left:9px; padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px; border-top:none; border-right:none; border-left:none"><span style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:black"><span style="font-weight:400"><span style="font-style:normal"><span style="text-decoration:none">TEXT</span></span></span></span></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Incredible. I was expecting hours of work and tweaking. But adding that one line for the CSS seems to have done the trick. Thanks!